# How do I iterate over/dereference an array of subroutine refs in Perl?

Tags: perl, function, iterator

I’m trying to figure out how to iterate over an array of subroutine refs.

What’s wrong with this syntax?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub yell { print "Ahh!\n"; }
sub kick { print "Boot!\n"; }
sub scream { print "Eeek!\n"; }

my @routines = (\&yell, \&kick, \&scream);
foreach my $routine_ref (@routines) {
  my &routine = &{$routine_ref};
  &routine;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know.  What did the perl interpretor say?

Comment: You're iterating over them just fine. It's dereferencing them that's the real question. :)

Comment: @Jon: It said I had a syntax error, but didn't suggest how to correct it. @brian d foy: Good point, I'll modify the title. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `foreach` loop, the following is a syntax error:

```
my &routine;
```

Your variable `$routine_ref` already has a reference to the subroutine, so all you need to do at that point is call it:

```
for my $routine_ref (@routines) {
    &{$routine_ref};
}
```

As always with Perl, "There's More Than One Way to Do It."  For example, if any of those subroutines took parameters, you could pass them inside parenthesis like this:

```
for my $routine_ref (@routines) {
  $routine_ref->();
}
```

Also note that I've used `for` instead of `foreach`, which is a best pratice put forth by [Damian Conway in Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735/).

Comment: I've always preferred the latter example, its less-ambiguous in behaviour to me.  ( +1 )

Comment: You probably don't want to dereference it with just the &. Without the parens, that uses the current value of @_ as the implicit argument list, and that's usually never what you mean to do.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach my $routine_ref (@routines) {
        $routine_ref->();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub yell { print "Ahh!\n"; }
sub kick { print "Boot!\n"; }
sub scream { print "Eeek!\n"; }

my @routines = (\&yell, \&kick, \&scream);
foreach my $routine_ref (@routines) {
  &$routine_ref ();
}
```

Comment: &$routine_ref calls it. The parens do nothing.